# Interpretation for squared Markov kernel?

Tags: markov-chains

Assume  a [Markov chain on a measurable state space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chains_on_a_measurable_state_space#Starting_in_a_single_point) $(E,\Sigma)$ is given, denoted by $(X_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ with Markov kernel $p$ and [stationary measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chains_on_a_measurable_state_space#Stationary_measure) $\mu$.

In this case, we have

$$ \mathbb{P}[X_0 \in A , \, X_1 \in B] = \int_A p(x,B) \, \mu(dx). $$

Is there a similar interpretation for the term

$$ \int_A \big(p(x,B)\big)^2 \mu(dx) ? $$

Answer (score 0):

I could figure out an interpretation when $p$ is reversible i.e.
$$ \int_A p(x,B) \, \mu(dx) = \int_B p(x,A) \,  \mu(dx) .$$

First by the reversible property we have
$$ \int_E  f(x) \int_E g(y)\, p(x,dy) \, \mu(dx) = \int_E g(x) \int_E f(y) \, p(x,dy) \, \mu(dx).$$
For $f(x) = p(x,A) 1_B(x)$ and for $g(x) = 1_A(x)$ we have

$$ \begin{align} \int_B p(x,A) \cdot p(x,A)  \, \mu(dx) &= \int_E f(x) \int_E g(y) \, p(x,dy) \mu(dx) \\
&= \int_E g(x) \int_E f(y) \, p(x,dy) \, \mu(dx) \\
&= \int_A\int_B p(y,A) \, p(x,dy) \, \mu(dx) \\
&= \mathbb{P}[X_0 \in A ,X_1 \in B , X_2 \in A] \end{align}$$